# Sharing links with query strings

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, query-string, sharing, social-media

I'm trying to set up a LinkedIn share button that needs to share a URL with a query string included. I've tried various combinations of encoding the URL but LinkedIn breaks every option either by removing everything starting with the "=" or by sharing a link with the "=" encoded to "%3D"

How am I supposed to get this to work or is LinkedIn just not going to fix this?

I've set a simple demo of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/09dopxm5/

For brevity sake, here's the Javascript I tried to generate a link that would work...

```js
var original_link = "https://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/2019/03/07/why-an-economic-slowdown-will-not-crush-real-estate-this-time/?a=311651-adc5cc7d14b39be55e90ff0b2b7bbf6a";

var link1 = escape(original_link);
var link2 = encodeURI(original_link);
var link3 = encodeURIComponent(original_link);

var linkedinLink = "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=";

document.getElementById("link-1").href = linkedinLink + link1;
document.getElementById("link-2").href = linkedinLink + link2;
document.getElementById("link-3").href = linkedinLink + link3;
document.getElementById("link-4").href = linkedinLink + original_link;
```

```html
<a href='#' id='link-1' target="_blank">Share Attempt 1</a><br/>
<a href='#' id='link-2' target="_blank">Share Attempt 2</a><br/>
<a href='#' id='link-3' target="_blank">Share Attempt 3</a><br/>
<a href='#' id='link-4' target="_blank">Share Attempt 4</a><br/>
```

EDIT - 
An added piece of info is that we are not sharing the URL that the user is currently on. We're trying to share a personalized version of the post they're currently viewing.

Comment: This seems like a security feature to prevent query strings being used for phishing attacks? Not sure it has anything to do with encoding. I've seen many companies on linkedin use a URL shortener/redirect for this purpose - I have no solution otherwise

Comment: Ugh. Really seems like an unnecessary burden but I guess I'll keep that as a backup.

Comment: Actually it looks like the shortened versions of our links break when posted by LinkedIn as well. This is ridiculous. I just tried sharing a bitly version of the URL manually on LinkedIn. They convert it into the full version and break the query string still.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution to use, using their API.
https://jsfiddle.net/yt9hzupw/#&togetherjs=J69Euy0GoC

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://google.com" data-counter="top"></script>
```

Comment: Taking a deeper look at what you sent now, but I should state that the URL we're sharing is different from the URL the user is currently on. Basically inside our member area we provide the button to share their personalized version of the post they're currently looking at.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like that suffers from the same issue. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Your third link works perfectly for me!  See:

[image]

So, that means the solution, in terms of JavaScript is...

```
var original_link = "https://www.simplifyingthemarket.com/en/2019/03/07/why-an-economic-slowdown-will-not-crush-real-estate-this-time/?a=311651-adc5cc7d14b39be55e90ff0b2b7bbf6a";

var link3 = encodeURIComponent(original_link);
var linkedinLink = "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=";
document.getElementById("link-3").href = linkedinLink + link3;
```

And your HTML solution is...

```
<a href='#' id='link-3' target="_blank">Share Attempt 3</a><br/>
```

In case you're uncertain, you can check with the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).

Also helpful:

- [**Microsoft LinkedIn Share Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin) : for URL formatting.
- [**LinkedIn Shareable Documentation**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) : for `og:` tag formatting.